How can I solve the scrollTrigger problem in Gsap?
I was working on a project based on Gsap. I wanted that while a div enters in the viewport from 90% top , there was a div in that parent div. Now, there was multiple elements in the first child of that topmost parent div.  The scrollTrigger property is not working , while checking into the console for responsiveness , it was working. But after returning into the large screen, and refresing , the problem is coming back. Please , can anyone solve it ?
I tried all the possible things, but didn't find the solution.
